# Ms sql - update one column table by another row by row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got one table (Table1) with some columns filled by data and one empty column. There is another table (Table2) with one column with data. There is no foreign key or any link to that tables just row numbers are equal. I want update empty column of Table1 by data from column of Table2 row by row (row1 from table2 to row1 from table1. Is any way to do it but not using export to file? Is possible to do that using while loop?

Comment: show the tables structure

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: There's no *row 1* or *row 2* in a DBMS, your updates will be kind of random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t1.*, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     )
update toupdate
    set col = t2.col
    from (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
          from table2 t2
         ) t2
    where t2.seqnum = t1.seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add rownumbers like this and join them:

```
WITH CTE_TableA AS(
SELECT ColA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY ColA) AS RowA
FROM TableA)

,CTE_TableB AS
SELECT ColB, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColB ORDER BY ColB) AS RowB
FROM TableB

SELECT * FROM CTE_TableA AS A
INNER JOIN CTE_TableB AS B ON A.RowA = B.RowB
```